# How to make 2020 Honda Accord ride more supple

Tags: tires, suspension

There is a fine line between sporty and harsh. I would like to make 2020 base Honda Accord sedan more supple, less harsh. From investigating online, it appears the reason may be the tires. The stock tires have low rolling resistance.

- Could tires affect the ride so substantially?
- Is there any reliable source (trade magazine, automotive magazine) that specifically state that Accord's sporty/harsh ride is due in large part to it's tires?
- What other, relatively affordable (<$500) methods exist to make a car's handling more supple?

Note: Tire-pressure has been checked against specs.i.e. not over-inflated.

Comment: Are they run-flat tires? Those naturally give a hard ride.

Answer (score 1):

So, check with a tire place if you can fit a higher profile tire to the existing rims or even change the rims and tires to get that change.

Lower profile tires are harsher than higher profile.
I have a 55 profile tire and am happy with its ride.

After that, you start to look into damper and spring settings.

Did you test drive the car before purchase - often one thing people pay attention to is the ride quality during a test drive.

Answer (score 0):

Your "under $500" qualification makes this likely impossible.

Some cheap options:

1. Experiment with LOWER tire pressure.  Usually the manufacturer specs a tire pressure for maximum fuel economy at the expense of ride harshness.  Try dropping a couple psi at a time and see if that helps.  I would check the tire manufacturer's data to see what they say is the minimum tire pressure and not go below that.
2. Put some weight in the back over the rear axle if possible.  Bags of sand can be used and are pretty cheap.  Of course now you will be hauling around this extra weight and it will impact your fuel economy but you said "under $500" in the question.
3. Get a seat cushion that will help isolate you from the road somewhat.

Some more reasonable options:

1. Do some research on alternate tires for your car with a focus on ride quality.
2. Change out the shock absorbers and/or struts for some adjustable one and adjust them for softer ride.
3. Buy and install some aftermarket springs or coil-overs that are softer than the OEM ones.
4. Get rid of this Accord and get a car that has a better ride quality.